# exception thrown in std::thread can't trigger function set by SetUnhandledExceptionFilter

Tags: c++, windows

I use VS2019 on Win10

Code:

```
LONG __stdcall DummyUnhandledExceptionFilter(PEXCEPTION_POINTERS pExceptionInfo)
{
    printf("DummyUnhandledExceptionFilter called\n");
    return EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_SEARCH;
}

int wmain(const int argc, const wchar_t* argv[])
{
    SetUnhandledExceptionFilter(DummyUnhandledExceptionFilter);

    std::thread crash(
        []()
        {
            Sleep(1 * 1000);
#if 0
            RaiseException(0, 0, 0, 0);    //可以触发
#elif 1
            throw std::exception();    //不能触发
#else
            int* p = 0;
            p[0] = 1;    //可以触发
#endif
        }
    );

    crash.join();
}
```

out of main thread, those three branches code with #if have different behavers，throw std::exception can't trigger DummyUnhandledExceptionFilter, but others does.

In *Windows via C++ 5th*, Chapter25 C++ Exceptions vs. Structured Exceptions, Jeffrey said:

> However, you should know that Microsoft's Visual C++ compiler has implemented C++ exception handling using the operating system's structured exception handling....In fact, when you write a C++ throw statement, the compiler generates a call to the Windows RaiseException function. ...

if him right, throw std::exception have nothing special, but they do have some different. I set breakpoint at asm view, throw called RaiseException, but why it can't trigger DummyUnhandledExceptionFilter?

And std::set_terminate give no help at all.

I'm so confused, please help me! thx all

Comment: I found that, use _beginthread to start a crash thread can trigger the function, so, it is std::thread have some thing?

Comment: [The `SetUnhandledExceptionFilter` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/structured-exception-handling) says "if an exception occurs in a process *that is **not** being debugged*..." (emphasis mine). So if you run in the debugger your function will *not* be called.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude hi, thank you for your comment, I noticed this direction and I test it without debugger.

Comment: [What happens to custom unhandled exception filters if a debugger is not running? - Old New Thing](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20180726-00/?p=99345)  Summary - "_...So don’t do that...."_

Comment: if `DummyUnhandledExceptionFilter` not called, mean that exception handled before it. `_beginthread` not set by self any exception handler around user thread callback, but `std::thread` probably do this. and filter can handle some exception and some pass up. so probably `throw ` exception is handled and `RaiseException` is not

Comment: The standard demands that std::terminate() gets called when an std::thread suffers an unhandled exception.  You have a reason to prefer CreateThread().  set_terminate() is supposed to help, we can't see it.  The lambda can be a problem, a fix [was planned](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/setunhandledexceptionfilter-callback-not-invoked-f/235602) for VS2017, version 15.8

Comment: I attempted use it for crash report, only record some infomation, means I don't want to cure the process, @RichardCritten.

Comment: for the reason upon, I can't limit to use std::thread, it's hard to comply with all crews. @RbMm

Comment: this issue may remains in VS2019 16.10? @HansPassant

Comment: *I attempted use it for crash report, only record some infomation* - you need use [*Vectored Exception Handling*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/vectored-exception-handling) - call [`AddVectoredExceptionHandler`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/errhandlingapi/nf-errhandlingapi-addvectoredexceptionhandler) instead `SetUnhandledExceptionFilter` - this (VEH) will be work in all case

Comment: @RbMm Thank you, this works fine! but my confuse not reduce at all, SetUnhandledExceptionFilter is not working, because std::thread hide the exception(is this right?), so UnhandledExceptionFilter can't triggered, but why VEH handler can be triggered? Is this a bug of VSC or Windows?

Comment: VEH handlers called first, before SEH handlers. std::thread set cpp exception handler. This is case of SEH handler. so even if std::thread handle ( but not "hide") exception, this not affect VEH handlers, which is already invoked. the SetUnhandledExceptionFilter called the last, after all VEH and SEH handlers and if nobody from it handle exception and debugger not attached to process

Comment: @RbMm May I ask where did you got all those details?

Comment: @RbMm, The 2nd parameter of AddVectoredExceptionHandle get called every time when throw statement executed, which is not I wanted, and AddVectoredContinueHandler acted same as SetUnhandledExceptionFilter.

Answer (score 0):

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/setunhandledexceptionfilter-callback-not-invoked-f/235602
This is a bug in msvc, which has been reported to Microsoft. The specific reason is stated in the post

Comment: Note that fixing the bug won't help OP. C++ exceptions in `std::thread` should never reach the unhandled exception filter. However, there is an MSVC bug that allows them through sometimes. Once the bug is fixed, OP's problem is still there.